# Mark all the functions by constexpr implicitly

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, constexpr

Are there reasons not to marking all the functions `contexpr` implicitly after C++11? I think the principle "Caedite eos! Novit enim Dominus qui sunt eius" would work here, because in case of:

```
template< typename T >
constexpr
T f(T t) { return t; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    f(1);
    f(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

`f(argc)` automatically recognized as not `constexpr`, as opposed to `f(1)`. On the one hand compiler can defenitely infer applicability of `constexpr` specifier by itself for functions, which can be `constexpr` generally, on the other hand it can ensure, that functions can never be `constexpr` if they not matches [the rules for `constexpr` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

Also there is a plenty of problems with *STL*. Say, regarding non-`constexpr` `operator []` of non-`const` `std::array` in constant expressions or regarding non-`constexpr` `std::swap`, which prevents using of `std::swap` in constant expressions.

Why there no such language feature as implicit `constexpr` specifier enabled by default for all the functions (or even for statements, expressions and subexpressions)? Is there performance reasons or something else?

Comment: It's not that easy. [Look at the mischief caused by adding `constexpr` to libc++'s `invoke` implementation](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23141).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You seem to be asking why we have to state that a function is `constexpr`, even though you realize that putting that designation on a function carries with it a number of syntactic restrictions. If you want to know why you have to explicitly declare a function `constexpr`, just look though the list of every limitation placed on `constexpr` functions. From the obvious to the template instantiation issues.

Comment: @T.C. `constexpr is causing function templates to be instantiated in unevaluated contexts that otherwise would not` sometimes it is of greate importance. Is this difference a language flaw?

Comment: @NicolBolas If I mark function as `constexpr` and put into its body e.g. `reinterpret_cast`, compiler easily show me the error. It is not as hard as binomial theorem for the compiler to prove, that all the requirements are holds. It is obvious conclusion for me. T.C. illustrate good example, when `constexpr` make difference in semantics. Broken syntactic restrictions can be easily recognized by compiler itself, why the user should deal with this — this was the question?

Comment: @Orient: the issue is that it's not considered acceptable to make breaking changes that could force large projects to rewrite their code, or to silently give that code substantially different meaning. It was quite difficult for them to figure out how to add features like move semantics without breaking old code. Even if the compiler can successfully report such problems, that's not the issue. `constexpr` is not quite mature enough to just be applied automatically everywhere, and/or was not intended that way, it seems.

Comment: @Orient: "*If I mark function as constexpr and put into its body e.g. reinterpret_cast, compiler easily show me the error. It is not as hard as binomial theorem for the compiler to prove, that all the requirements are holds.*" You just explained why `constexpr` *shouldn't* be the default case. Making it the default case would break just about every C++ program. It would break *Hello, World!*, the most basic of C++ programs (due to `cout` or `printf` use). It would force people to go to the *vast* majority of their functions and add the `not_constexpr` keyword.

Comment: @NicolBolas Seems it is not clear from the question, but I mean, that in case of breaking of the `constexpr` rules, compiler should conclude, that function is not `constexpr`. On my mind, compiler should apply `constexpr` every time, when it can do it. There is *constant folding* optimization in compilers, I mean the same thing, but WRT more complex cases. All branches, functions, subexpressions, which cannot be evaluated at compile time should remain runtime.

Comment: The compiler will already do constant folding and such, whether things are marked `constexpr` or not. The compiler will already aggressively optimize your code if it can do it without changing the meaning (in ways that would be prohibited by the standard). Most of the time, `constexpr` really doesn't do that much except make it legal for you to use the results of the computations as template parameters. In some cases you can make the compiler do something at compile time that it would have done at runtime, but in most cases it already does the optimal thing.

Comment: @Orient: `constexpr` really needs to be treated differently than optimizations, because of its role in template parameters. Naively, you might think that any expressions which are simple enough for the compiler, should be legal as a template parameter. But what is simple for one compiler, may be difficult for another. The standard does not *require* any particular optimizations. `constexpr` is different, it creates a portable class of things which can be template parameters. I don't want to write a program on gcc, but clang says "X cannot be a template parameter, go rewrite your whole program"